# How to identify Irrelevant Usecases?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am modeling an use case diagram for point of sale system. Can I show use cases like "**Enter to store**" in my use case diagram?

It is irrelevant for the system I think to show use cases like "**Enter to store**".

Am I right? Are these irrelevant or should I show them?

Answer (score 2):

"Enter to store" is no use case at all. It does not bring any added value to the actor. It is either a constraint to other use cases (e.g. `{ must have entered store }`) or it is a simple action in some other use case.

So you are best off removing them.

Answer (score 0):

The "boss rule of thumb" is nice.
If your boss is satisfied if the actor does this all day long, chances are you have a good usecase.
If not, chances are you have to revise it.

This is at least good for a high-level overview.

Example:

- "purchase product" -> passes
- "view comments" --> fails